# Need help optimizing database query. Very unexperienced with indices

Tags: database, optimization, indexing, postgresql

I need to optimize this query. The professor recommends using indices, but i'm very confused about how. If I could get just one example of what a good index is and why, and the actual code needed, I could definitely do the rest by myself. Any help would be awesome. (PSQL btw)

```
    SELECT 
      x.enteredBy
      , x.id
      , count(DISTINCT xr.id)
      , count(DISTINCT c.id)
      , 'l'
 FROM 
      ((locationsV x left outer join locationReviews xr on x.id = xr.lid)
       left outer join reviews r on r.id = xr.id) 
       left outer join comments c on xr.id = c.reviewId
 WHERE 
      x.vNo = 0  
      AND (r.enteredBy IS NULL OR 
            (r.enteredBy <> x.enteredBy 
             AND c.enteredBy <> x.enteredBy
             AND r.enteredBY NOT IN 
                       (SELECT requested FROM friends WHERE requester = x.enteredBY)
             AND r.enteredBY NOT IN 
                       (SELECT requester FROM friends WHERE requested = x.enteredBY)))
     AND (c.enteredBy IS NULL OR 
             (c.enteredBY NOT IN 
                       (SELECT requested FROM friends WHERE requester = x.enteredBY)
             AND c.enteredBY NOT IN 
                       (SELECT requester FROM friends WHERE requested = x.enteredBY)))
 GROUP BY 
     x.enteredBy
     , x.id
```

I tried adding something like this to the beginning, but the overall time it took didn't change.

```
CREATE INDEX friends1_idx ON friends(requested);
CREATE INDEX friends2_idx ON friends(requester);
```

Comment: Anyone see any other optimizations to be made?

Answer (score 1):

I think the SQL itself could be optimized to improve performance in addition to looking at indexes.  Having those `IN` clauses in the WHERE clause may cause the optimizer do full table scans.  So if you could move those to be tables in the `FROM` section you would have better performance.  Also, having the `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` clauses in in the `SELECT` statement seems problematic.  You would likely be better off if you could make changes so the DISTINCT clauses were necessary there and simply use the COUNT aggregate function.

Consider using a SQL statement in the `FROM` clause before you do the left join--a structure something like this:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT ... FROM Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 ON ...) AS Table4 ON
        Table1.somecolumn = Table4.somecolumn
...
```

I know this isn't giving you the solution, but hopefully it will help you to think about other aspects of the problem and to explore other ways to address performance.

Comment: Thanks! Any additional tips for an indexes?

Comment: I think it is best to use the DB profiling tools to suggest the indexes rather than try to guess yourself.  Most DBs will have tools that let you run a SQL command that will be analyzed for index suggestions.  Beyond that, you want an index that will differentiate things.  If you index a column where 90% of the values are the same, it probably won't be too useful unless you are looking for something in the 10%.  A column with lots of unique values may be a better one to index on.  You also want to index on columns that are used in your query--perhaps "requestor" or "requested" in your case.